# Java - even though the decimal number places below 5, be rouding up

Tags: java, math

I have this:

```
return ((Double) Math.ceil(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()) / 10)).intValue();
```

I need a number **even though the decimal number places below 5, be rouding up**.

Using this code, I have these examples:

```
((Double) Math.ceil(14 / 10).intValue() = 1
((Double) Math.ceil(26 / 10).intValue() = 3
((Double) Math.ceil(25 / 10).intValue() = 3
```

I need:

```
((Double) Math.ceil(14 / 10).intValue() = 2
((Double) Math.ceil(26 / 10).intValue() = 3
((Double) Math.ceil(25 / 10).intValue() = 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dividing integers gives you integers. There is nothing for `Math.ceil()` to do, because the number you get isn't 1.4, it's 1. Convert at least one of your numbers to double before dividing:

e.g.

```
((Double) Math.ceil(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()) / 10.)).intValue();
```

or

```
((Double) Math.ceil(Double.parseDouble(matcher.group()) / 10.)).intValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you int division to double division, for example as `14 / 10D`.

Currently your 14/10 results in 1...

Answer (score 1):

```
return (int) Math.ceil(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()) / 10.0));
```

Also take care not to use integer division, 26/10 = 2.